# R update tbl object into redshift

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift db into which i am updating values from R using the copy_to command. 
The class of the variable being inserted into R is:

```
class(df)
[1] "tbl_dbi"  "tbl_sql"  "tbl_lazy" "tbl"
```

The copy_to command used is:

```
copy_to(acc_conn, df,name = "test_output",temporary = FALSE)
```

The copy_to command however does only insert and not update. 
Is there any other possibility of updating a redshift table?

Comment: what package are you using? is that dplyr?

Comment: Yes it is dplyr package.

Comment: and by updating do you mean append or upsert?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is upsert.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an extensive blogpost explaining a lot of nuances of reading/writing data to/from Amazon Redshift: https://auth0.com/blog/a-comprehensive-guide-for-connecting-with-r-to-redshift/

In particular, the best way to read data with R is using the RPostgres library, and to write data i recommend using the R Package i created: https://github.com/sicarul/redshiftTools

In particular, it has the rs_upsert_table function, which does an upsert of your data.frame, using your example:

`rs_upsert_table(df, dbcon=acc_conn, table_name="test_output", bucket="mybucket", split_files=4)`

You'll need an S3 bucket and the AWS keys to access it, since this package uploads to S3 and then directs redshift to that bucket, it's the fastest way to bulk upload data.